# how to dismiss a modal presentation of UISplitController in Portrait orientation

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

my project is in swift 2 and works in both orientation.

i have a UISplitViewController presented modally.

in the navigation bar of master view i have a bar button for dismiss this.

when i open the controller in landscape mode the close button work well because master view is always visibile and his parent and presenting view controller are ok.

the problem is in the portrait orientation because master view isn't always visible and his parent and presenting controller are null when i tap the cancel button.

there is a solution?

thanks in advance

**presenting controller**

i present a modal splitViewController from storyboard:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

if segue.identifier == "splitSegue" {

    let split = segue.destinationViewController as! UISplitViewController
    let masterNav = split.viewControllers[0] as! UINavigationController
    let master = masterNav.topViewController as! MasterController
    master.delegate = self
}}
```

and this is the delegate fun for dismiss:

```
func updateAppCategory(master: MasterController) {

    self.presentedViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had have the same issue and found a solution:

```
splitViewController!.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible
```

When you insert this in viewdidload, then you can dismiss the splitviewcontroller in portrait and landscape mode

Answer (score 2):

The apple recommended way of dismissing the presented view controller is, letting the presenting view controller handle the dismissal. The view controller that's presented shouldn't dismiss itself.

Use a delegate approach, make a `didPressCancel` method in the delegate, and call it when user press cancel. And from presenting view controller, in the implementation of this method, dismiss the presented view controller.

Comment: i'm sorry, i have another little problem..with delegate in portrait orientation when i dismiss the split view controller from presenting only the detail is dismissed, not the master, why?

Comment: How are you presenting, can you add your code to the question?

Comment: Apple recommended way of having split view is to use it as root view. there're complexities in setting delegate to master view or detail view because in portrait, there's no master view.

Answer (score 1):

Edgar's solution works however if you don't want to use that display mode you can just set `PreferredDisplayMode.AllVisible` immediately prior to dismissing the Split View (instead of in `ViewDidLoad`)

This is the Xamarin.iOS code I used in my master controller. Works in portrait and landscape.

```
partial void btnExitModalSplitViewControllerAllOrientations_Activated(UIBarButtonItem sender)
{
    SplitViewController.PreferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible;
    SplitViewController.DismissViewController(true, null);
}
```